# Copy all elements of 1 array into a second array at a specific index in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Im trying to copy elements of arr1 into arr2 at index n. The elements must be copied in the exact order they're in. I can get the code to work when I loop through the arrow backwards but I cant pass the tests because its not in order.

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let newArr = arr2.splice(" ");
  for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length;i++) {
      newArr.splice(n,0,arr1[i]);
  }
  return  console.log(newArr);
}
```

An example of how this should be called is `frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1);`
Expected output is `[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]`
I keep getting `[ 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 ]`

Comment: What is your sample input and the expected output?

Comment: frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1); expected output is [4, 1, 2, 3, 5]. I keep getting       [ 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 ]

Comment: And what should this produce?

Comment: Why is `6` deleted in the expected output?

Comment: Your output looks correct. The expected output seems like is for `frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 1);`

Comment: Why are you using a string as the first argument to `splice()`? The first argument is the starting index.

Comment: `return console.log(...)` makes the function return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the 6 is getting deleted but maybe something like this:

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let newArr = arr2
  newArr.splice(n+1)
  for(let i = arr1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      newArr.splice(n,0,arr1[i]);
  }
  return  console.log(newArr);
}

frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1);
```

Comment: Why use jsfiddle when [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) are available?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your output is coming backwards is because you keep inserting at the same position `n`. This pushes the previous element after it, so they end up in reverse order. If you increment `n` each time through the loop, you'll insert them in order.

But there's no need for a loop, use spread syntax to use all of `arr1` as the arguments in a single call to `splice()`.

```js
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let newArr = [...arr2]; // make copy of arr2
  newArr.splice(n, 0, ...arr1); // splice arr1 into the copy
  return newArr;
}

console.log(frankenSplice([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 1));
```

I don't understand why you don't expect `6` in the output.